# white-space after/before background image repeat

Tags: css

I am using `background-repeat:repeat-x;` to repeat a background image horizontally, but I noticed that there is a white space after the earlier image and before the next image.

How can I get rid of this white-space?

Here is the page where this is happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/search/new.html

One may have to make the browser window wider to see the landscape background image repeat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little transparency on each side is in the image file. Crop the image.

Comment: +1 I couldn't find it in the `.png` version, but the OP URL now works!

Comment: which image file? the .png or .svg?

Comment: looks like both. Is there a way in css to move one background to the left some as I don't know how to crop an svg

Answer (score 0):

Using the Chome Developer Tool, you can see that your SVG file is one pixel larger than the PNG version. The SVG is also layered higher and (because of the size difference) is scaling differently than the PNG. Try cropping the image or switching the order of the layers -

From

```
background: url(dawn.png) top left repeat-x;
background: url(dawn.svg) top left repeat-x;
```

To:

```
background: url(dawn.svg) top left repeat-x;
background: url(dawn.png) top left repeat-x;
```

Comment: well, what I was trying to do with that is to rewrite the first background rule with the .svg background rule. That way when .svg in css backgrounds are not supported, it falls back to the .png rule.